# AWS Amplify mock function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, function, aws-amplify

I have frustratingly been trying to mock functions using AWS amplify.

For some reason they always timeout, regardless of what I set the --timeout to.

I have recently come across a solution a thought I would post it as an answer.

Comment: Please add more info about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I change the handler from

`exports.handler = async (event) => {`
to 
`const mainFunct = async () => {`

and call the funtion using `mainFunct();` at the end of the index.js file

you can install the `aws-sdk` using your terminal and going all the way into the function's `....\src` directory.
then running `\src> npm install missing-modules` for whatever modules are missing.

-Just remember to update your `.gitignore` to not commit the node-modules folder in the function's src folder. (So many files ...)

Then simply run the function as if it's a node.js file. 
`C:\path\to\function\src> node index.js`

you can also add an output file, which I find making my console.log() statements a lot easier to read and debug on
`C:\path\to\function\src> node index.js > functionOutputFile.json`

Works for me so far and couldn't find anything online about this...

Comment: Most commonly, a Lambda Function needs input, in the form of an event. I recommend using a testing framework, like Mocha, to act as an entry point. You can import your lambda's handler in the test suite and invoke it like a function, passing an event structure.

Comment: If you could provide a code example it would really clarify. because I cannot reproduce your answer at all.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of info about running lambda functions locally on the [Amplify website](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli). You can invoke the function directly with `amplify mock myfunction`, or use `amplify mock` with a GraphQL API.
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/mock

NB: REST APIs cannot be mocked locally currently.

I used `amplify function add` to make a function, then I modified my GraphQL API's schema to proxy to the lambda locally using the `@function` directive.
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/function

You may need to configure your function with environment variables. The Amplify team recently added support via .env files,
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/mock#function-mock-environment-variables